# WSO2 Identity Server sso-idp-config.xml Reference

Tags: xml, configuration-files, wso2, wso2-identity-server

Is there a complete reference spelling out all valid fields you can use and configure in the sso-idp-config.xml.  There's no DTD or schema that I know of... at least not referenced in the file.  There documentation on it at least?  I looked, but could not find.

Answer (score 1):

Full configuration of a SAML2 service provider created in sso-idp-config.xml

```
<!--ServiceProvider>
    <Issuer></Issuer>
    <AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
      <AssertionConsumerServiceURL></AssertionConsumerServiceURL>
    </AssertionConsumerServiceURLs>
    <DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL></DefaultAssertionConsumerServiceURL>
    <EnableSingleLogout>true</EnableSingleLogout>
    <SLOResponseURL></SLOResponseURL>
    <SLORequestURL></SLORequestURL>
    <SAMLDefaultSigningAlgorithmURI>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1</SAMLDefaultSigningAlgorithmURI>
    <SAMLDefaultDigestAlgorithmURI>http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1</SAMLDefaultDigestAlgorithmURI>
    <SignResponse>true</SignResponse>
    <ValidateSignatures>true</ValidateSignatures>
    <EncryptAssertion>true</EncryptAssertion>
    <CertAlias></CertAlias>
    <EnableAttributeProfile>true</EnableAttributeProfile>
    <IncludeAttributeByDefault>true</IncludeAttributeByDefault>
    <ConsumingServiceIndex></ConsumingServiceIndex>
    <EnableAudienceRestriction>false</EnableAudienceRestriction>
    <AudiencesList>
      <Audience></Audience>
    </AudiencesList>
    <EnableRecipients>false</EnableRecipients>
    <RecipientList>
      <Recipient></Recipient>
    </RecipientList>
    <EnableIdPInitiatedSSO>false</EnableIdPInitiatedSSO>
    <EnableIdPInitSLO>false</EnableIdPInitSLO>
    <ReturnToURLList>
      <ReturnToURL></ReturnToURL>
    </ReturnToURLList>
  </ServiceProvider-->
```

Can you please refer this link [sso-idp-config.xml configurations](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Configuring+a+SP+and+IdP+Using+Configuration+Files) for more details